# Making a dictionary of words per paragraph per chapter (key) of a book

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

For some context:
I start my code with a list 'Book' which is a list of strings and each string is a line in the book. The paragraphs are divided by empty stings. There are five chapters in the book, with the titles 'I', 'II', 'III', 'IV' and 'V', and those titles are separated from the previous and following chapters by two empty strings.
Basically:

```
book = ['I', '', '', 'line1', 'line2', '', 'line3', line4', '', '', 'II', '' , '',......]
```

My goal is to make a dictionary where the keys are the chapter titles and the value for each key is a list containing the number of words that each paragraph (excluding the chapter title) has in the chapter:

```
chapter_words = {'I':[2, 2], 'II': [3,6,7], ....}
```

I first separated paragraphs and created a dictionary in the format {chapter : [paragraphs]}, where for each chapter title, the value is a list where each string is a different paragraph. I used .isupper() because previously I had to use a fuction that made all text lowercase.

```
chapter_paragraphs = {}
    current_chapter = []
    current_paragraph = []

    for line in book:
        if line.upper() in ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V']:
            if current_chapter:
                chapter_paragraphs[current_chapter] = current_paragraph
                current_paragraph= []

            current_chapter = line.upper()

        elif line:
            if not current_paragraph:
                current_paragraph.append(line)

            else:
                current_paragraph[-1] += ' ' + line

    if current_chapter:
        chapter_paragraphs[current_chapter] = current_paragraph
```

Going back to my example, this will create a dict `chapter_paragraphs = {'I': ['line1 line2', 'line3 line4'], ...}`

Next, I want to create a new dictionary chapter_words where, for each chapter title, the value is a list where each element is the number words in one of the paragraphs in the chapter, like this: `chapter_words = {'I': [2, 1], ...}` (like I explained in the begining). This is my attempt:

```
   chapter_words = {}

    for chapter, paragraphs in chapter_paragraphs.items():
        words_per_parag = []

        for parag in paragraphs:
            words = parag.split()
            count = len(words)
            words_per_paragraph.append(count)

        chapter_words[chapter] = words_per_paragraph
```

The problem is, instead of a list where each element is the number of words in one paragraph, the values on this dict are the total number of words in each chapter. Can anyone help me find out the mistake in the code? This is probably something very basic, but I've tried so many things and couldn't make it right! Thank you in advance!

Comment: I recommend that you debug your code to figure out where it is doing something different from what you want. This is a critical skill to learn as you are learning to program since we often write code incorrectly the first time. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips to get you started.

Comment: It looks like there's a small typo in your code. When appending the count of words in a paragraph to the list `words_per_parag`, you are using a variable `count`, but the list is called `words_per_paragraph`. So, you need to change `words_per_paragraph.append(count)` to `words_per_parag.append(count)`?

Comment: Here's the [fixed code](https://textdoc.co/BnM7yOFXEthizGeR).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools` bult-in module for the task:

```py
book = [
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "I",
    "",
    "",
    "line1",
    "line2",
    "",
    "line3",
    "line4",
    "",
    "",
    "II",
    "",
    "",
    "line1",
    "line2",
    "line3",
    "",
    "line4",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
]

from itertools import accumulate, groupby, zip_longest

l = {"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V"}

tmp = []
for a, b, c in zip_longest(book, book[1:], book[2:]):
    tmp.append(a in l and b == "" and c == "")

out = {}
for _, g1 in groupby(zip(accumulate(tmp), book), lambda v: v[0]):
    h = next(g1)[1]
    for k, g2 in groupby(g1, lambda v: v[1] != ""):
        if k:
            out.setdefault(h, []).append(" ".join(v for _, v in g2))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{'I': ['line1 line2', 'line3 line4'], 'II': ['line1 line2 line3', 'line4']}
```